# Setting up cakephp 2.0 on bluehost

Tags: cakephp, installation, bluehost

Hi I just thought I would share this here 
I am new to cakephp and I had just finished my site locally 
And wanted to push it to my production server @ bluehost

After I pushed it I was receiving a 500 error 
After 2 day of "no dice" I got it to work
here is what I did:

1) cut and paste the contents of the webroot folder to the root folder 
then I opened the new index.php file and changed the following:

```
if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).DS.'public_html'.DS.'my-site');
}
```

and

```
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR',DS.'app');
}
```

Done!
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're referring to specified in the CakePHP book under [Advanced Installation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html).